# Replacing a certain substring within a string - .Replace() method not working for me C#

Tags: c#, string, replace

I am currently working on a program and need to use the .Replace() method to remove a certain substring from a string. However, the code just doesn't seem to be working.

Below is the code I am using:

```
if (filter.Contains("AND [Type]"))
        {
            String test = "AND [Type] = '" + type + "'";
            filter.Replace(test, "");
        }
        else if (filter.Contains("Type") == true)
        {
            String test = "[Type] = '" + type + "'";
            filter.Replace(test, "");
        }
```

I have debugged the code and when stepping through it String test is set to exactly what is contained within the filter - however the code just runs through attempts the replace method but leaves the filter unchanged.

Is there any other way I can attempt to get this working or do I need to take a few steps back and come up with another idea for getting this working?

Comment: strings in C# are immutable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must assign the value to given string:

```
filter = filter.Replace(test, "");
```

`Replace()` returns a new string, more [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the replace to a variable so `filter = filter.Replace(test, "");`

Its a common issue with some of the functions like date adding hours, string replace..

Comment: I knew this as well as I've used the method in another part of my code! I debugged for agers and didn't notice the simple error - Thanks!

Comment: @benjiiiii as I said, its a common mistake ..  its easy to miss for that reason

Answer (score 0):

Look at he function definition string.Replace returns your new string:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx